# Do Until Loop - Delete Range Doesn't actually stop VBA

Tags: vba, loops, excel

Hi I have code for a do until loop that deletes a range that I defined. However, once it reaches the "Until" parameter I specified, it continues to delete my range. Why does it continue to delete? And how can I make it actually stop deleting once RowCount = 155?

```
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim Dados As Worksheet

Set Dados = Sheets("Dados")
RowCount = Dados.Cells(Rows.Count, "BL").End(xlUp).Row
Do
    Range("BL5:BP5").Delete
Loop Until RowCount = 155
```

Comment: There is nothing in your code incrementing `RowCount`.  For all the code knows, `RowCount` is set once and if it's not 155, it will never equal 155...

Comment: Move the definition of the RowCount into your Do Until Loop

Comment: @Chrismas007 moving the declaration doesnt do anything to solve the issue.  They need to increment the counter so after Range("BL5:BP5").Delete there should be a RowCount = RowCount + 1

Comment: Redefining it is the same thing. Also you'd want to use `- 1` since it is deleting rows.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine G and H are your BL:BP area:

[image]

What it seems you are asking is to shift up the Data below the Stuff to Delete for a certain amount to get this:

[image]

In your example, you could do this by:

```
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim Dados As Worksheet

Set Dados = Sheets("Dados")
RowCount = Dados.Cells(Rows.Count, "BL").End(xlUp).Row
Dados.Range("BL5:BP" & RowCount - 155).Delete xlShiftUp
```

Comment: what happens when the code is run a second or third time, will there be a possibility that row count is 160 or less?

Comment: @Davesexcel probably could use some validation.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting it to go with this code.

```
Sub Newlastmonths()

Dim RowCount As Long
Dim Dados As Worksheet
Dim LeaveRows As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Set Dados = Sheets("Dados")
RowCount = Dados.Cells(Rows.Count, "BL").End(xlUp).Row
LeaveRows = RowCount - 156
x = 5
y = x + LeaveRows

For i = x To y
    Range("BL" & i & ":BP" & i).Delete
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Crap. I didn't even see yours before I posted that.

Answer (score -1):

You could approach your loop a little differently

```
Dim RowCount As Long
Dim Dados As Worksheet
Dim iRows As Integer

Set Dados = Sheets("Dados")
RowCount = Dados.Cells(Rows.Count, "BL").End(xlUp).Row
For iRows = 1 to RowCount
    Range("BL5:BP5").Delete
Next iRows
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all.  It just keeps deleting the same Range over and over again.

Comment: @Chrismas007 Do you know what the OP is looking for? I fixed the loop issue. OP has been unclear about what is or isn't supposed to be deleted?

Comment: I think I do take a look at my answer.  I don't see your edit posted tho that fixed your loop.

Comment: This answer actually gave me an idea that helped me get it. I posted the code below.